# Call didSelectRowAtIndex for Custom Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have a cell that has two UIButton properties(nameLabel and profileImageButton) that are used to view the posts' user profile page. I am trying to get the user from the current cell but the didSelectRowAtIndex is not being called. I realize that this is suppose to happen(the method not being called)  but I do not know how to get around it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
postCell *cell = (postCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell"];

cell.personStringPost.text = [object objectForKey:@"stringPost"];
[cell.nameLabel setTitle:[object objectForKey:@"User_Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.userId = [object objectForKey:@"userId"];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"profileImage"];
NSData *data = [imageFile getData];
cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

cell.nameLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
postCell *cell = (postCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.userId = cell.userId;
NSLog(@"Did Select: %@", self.userId);
}

- (void) buttonPressed: (id) sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"personProfile" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Why do you want didSelectRow to be called, since you're doing your segue in the button method anyway?

Comment: If you know what the "current cell" is, can't you just get the user from it?

Comment: Because I need to pass data from the current cell to the next view controller. And I do not know what the current cell is, thats my problem. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called when I press the buttons so I do not know what the cell data is @HotLicks

Comment: @rdelmar I need to get data from the selected cell

Comment: You shouldn't get data from a cell. Your button's tag gives you the row that was selected. You should use that as an index into the array you use to populate the table.

Comment: If you know what button was pressed, you know what cell it is.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You actually want to get the data from the cell, rather than from your data source.  **Don't do that.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

// Selects and deselects rows. These methods `will not call` the delegate methods (-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:), nor will it send out a notification.

So replace the `selectRowAtIndexPath` in buttonPressed with the following two lines:

```
postCell *cell = (postCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.userId = cell.userId;
```

Comment: Very bad practice.  The userId should be accessed from the dataSource.